# Java Non-Capturing Regex Group gives "null" captures

Tags: java, regex, regex-group

I've got a java regex with (?:) formatted non-capturing groups, and I can't understand why it gives "null" matches for the non-capturing groups.

If I shorten the regex below to "@te(st)(?:aa)?" with the same ?: non-capturing group, it gives what I would consider expected behavior, matching only 1 group and the full match.

See the regex below:

```
package com.company;

import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final String regex = "@test\\s+([:.\\w\\\\x7f-\\xff]+)(?:[\\t ]+(\\S*))?(?:[\\t ]+(\\S*))?\\s*$";
        final String string = "    /**\n     * @test     TestGroup\n     */\n";

        final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
        final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

        while (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println("Full match: " + matcher.group(0));
            for (int i = 1; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
                System.out.println("Group " + i + ": " + matcher.group(i));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

```
Full match: @test     TestGroup
Group 1: TestGroup
Group 2: null
Group 3: null
```

Result of "@te(st)(?:aa)?" with same code:

```
Full match: @test
Group 1: st
```

What is it about the first regex that matches the non-capturing groups as null?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Answer

This is the regex pattern in the question:

```
"@test\\s+([:.\\w\\\\x7f-\\xff]+)(?:[\\t ]+(\\S*))?(?:[\\t ]+(\\S*))?\\s*$"
```

This regex pattern has three capturing groups:

1. `([:.\\w\\\\x7f-\\xff]+)`
2. `(\\S*)`
3. `(\\S*)`

So your first example is not matching the non-capturing groups as `null`. Instead, as expected, it is matching the last two capturing groups as `null`.

#### Another example that matches all capturing groups

If we change the example string to be matched to something that can match all three capturing groups in the pattern, we would see three matches. For example:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final String regex = "@test\\s+([:.\\w\\\\x7f-\\xff]+)(?:[\\t ]+(\\S*))?(?:[\\t ]+(\\S*))?\\s*$";
        final String string = "foo @test : bar baz\n";
        // final String string = "    /**\n     * @test     TestGroup\n     */\n";

        final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
        final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

        while (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println("Full match: " + matcher.group(0));
            for (int i = 1; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
                System.out.println("Group " + i + ": " + matcher.group(i));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The output of the above code is:

```
Full match: @test : bar baz

Group 1: :
Group 2: bar
Group 3: baz
```

A few more examples in other languages follow to show that this behaviour is more or less the same across implementations.

#### Python Example

```
import re

regex = re.compile('@test\\s+([:.\\w\\\\x7f-\\xff]+)(?:[\\t ]+(\\S*))?(?:[\\t ]+(\\S*))?\\s*$', re.MULTILINE)
s1 = '    /**\n     * @test     TestGroup\n     */\n'
s2 = 'foo @test : bar baz';

match = re.search(regex, s1)
for i in range(regex.groups + 1):
    print('Group {}: {}'.format(i, match.group(i)))
print()

match = re.search(regex, s2)
for i in range(regex.groups + 1):
    print('Group {}: {}'.format(i, match.group(i)))
```

The output is:

```
Group 0: @test     TestGroup
Group 1: TestGroup
Group 2: None
Group 3: None

Group 0: @test : bar baz
Group 1: :
Group 2: bar
Group 3: baz
```

The second match shows that capturing groups within non-capturing groups are indeed matched. The only thing that is little different with Python is that the groups that does not match do not appear in the output in the first example.

#### JavaScript Example

```
var regex = new RegExp('@test\\s+([:.\\w\\\\x7f-\\xff]+)(?:[\\t ]+(\\S*))?(?:[\\t ]+(\\S*))?\\s*$', 'm')
var s1 = '    /**\n     * @test     TestGroup\n     */\n'
var s2 = 'foo @test : bar baz';
var i

var result = regex.exec(s1)
for (i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
    console.log('result[' + i + '] :', result[i])
}
console.log()

var result = regex.exec(s2)
for (i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
    console.log('result[' + i + '] :', result[i])
}
```

The output is:

```
result[0] : @test     TestGroup
result[1] : TestGroup
result[2] : undefined
result[3] : undefined

result[0] : @test : bar baz
result[1] : :
result[2] : bar
result[3] : baz
```

#### PHP Example

```
<?php
$regex = "/@test\\s+([:.\\w\\\\x7f-\\xff]+)(?:[\\t ]+(\\S*))?(?:[\\t ]+(\\S*))?\\s*$/m";
$s1 = "    /**\n     * @test     TestGroup\n     */\n";
$s2 = "foo @test : bar baz";

preg_match($regex, $s1, $matches);
for ($i = 0; $i < count($matches); $i++) {
    echo "Match $i: $matches[$i]\n";
}
echo "\n";

preg_match($regex, $s2, $matches);
for ($i = 0; $i < count($matches); $i++) {
    echo "Match $i: $matches[$i]\n";
}
?>
```

The output is:

```
Match 0: @test     TestGroup
Match 1: TestGroup

Match 0: @test : bar baz
Match 1: :
Match 2: bar
Match 3: baz
```

Comment: Thanks! Seems obvious now, but the capturing groups are embedded in non-capturing groups. Certain other languages handle that differently. Will try to remember to mark as accepted in 3-4 minutes when I can.

Comment: @user1122069 Which implementation do you think handles it differently?

Comment: PHP's preg_match. Also regex101.com which uses that. Try @(?:test(aa)?) there.

Comment: @user1122069 Well, I tried `@(?:test(aa)?)` and it says, "1st Capturing Group (aa)?" implying that this implementation also handles it similarly, i.e., capturing group within non-capturing group is present in the result. In fact `aa` appears in the result too as the first match. See https://regex101.com/r/IDaBQv/2.

Comment: Try with just "test" won't return the "null" group. Just talking about the null vs. empty diff. The grammar parser and the executor are separate there. With PHP preg_match("/@(?:test(aa)?)/", "@test...", $match);var_dump($match); t does not give the null groups, but will match aa if given.

Comment: Looks like a bug or limitation in PHP/PCRE, as it will skip the dd capture without the aa. preg_match("/@(?:test(aa)?).+(dd)?/", "@test...dd", $match);var_dump($match);

Comment: @user1122069 Yes, there indeed seems to be a problem with `preg_match`. `preg_match("/(f.*)?:(b.*)?:(b.*)?/", "foo::", $match);` returns `$match = ["foo::", "foo"]` but `preg_match("/(f.*)?:(b.*)?:(b.*)?/", "foo::baz", $match);` returns `$match = ["foo::", "foo", "", "baz"]`. Strangely, the output seems to indicate that `(b.*)` matched `""` (a zero-length string) but in reality it matched nothing. `NULL` would have been more appropriate instead of `""`. Java, Python, and JavaScript return `null`, `None`, and `undefined`, respectively, for the group that does not match any part of the string.